# Android Cordova/Phonegap Error net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, webview

I am having an error in a Cordova Android app I am making that is pretty simple: Open a webpage on start.

The webpage I am trying to open is https://gpasas.com, that is from one of my clients, but when I export the APK and try to open the app, android opens an alert that says: "net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

I don't really know what's going on, and I guess it has to do with the https. I think so because I made another app [1] that doesn't crash and is in the playstore, but that webpage I try to open has no SSL.

Is any other person having the same problem?

[1. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.otherwisestudios.webpage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.otherwisestudios.webpage)

Comment: No, it is Angular JS